# How to add an edit buttons in DataTables plugin?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using DataTables plugin to make a table in my project and I would like to add an edit button in my table. I use this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ptyw29az/12/) to know how make a button but in my project it doesn't work and I don't know why.

My code :

```
function make_table(data_table) {
    var data_use = get_data_table(data_table);
    var column_name = [{
        title: name_layer
    }, {
        title: $.S.trans.SHAR.title_table2
    }, {
        title: $.S.trans.SHAR.title_table3
    }, {
        title: $.S.trans.SHAR.title_table1
    }]; 
    $('#datatable').dataTable({ 
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        data : data_use,
        columns : column_name,
        dom : 'Bfrtip',
        select : 'single',
        responsive : true,
        altEditor : true,
        destroy : true,
        searching: false,
        buttons : [{
            extend : 'selected',
            text : 'Edit',
            name : 'edit'
        }],
    });
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: They are no error in the console.

Comment: Can you provide your full code with sample data in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Link to JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/09tnsk2m/8/
To the code work on JSFiddle I just delete the lang option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include [Buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/), [Select](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/), [Editor](https://editor.datatables.net/) and (optional) [Responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extensions.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cqf1zp3a/) is a simple working example based on your code.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Datatables</title>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <link rel="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.2/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="datatablecontainer">
            <table class="dataTable" id="datatable"></table>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://kingkode.com/datatables.editor.lite/js/altEditor/dataTables.altEditor.free.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data_use = [
        ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422"],
        ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562"],
        ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224"],
        ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407"],
    ];

    var column_name = [{
        title: "table_1"
    }, {
        title: "table2"
    }, {
        title: "table3"
    }, {
        title: "table4"
    }];

    $('#datatable').DataTable({
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        data : data_use,
        columns : column_name,
        dom : 'Bfrtip',
        select : 'single',
        responsive : true,
        altEditor : true,
        //destroy : true,
        searching: false,
        buttons : [{
            extend : 'selected',
            text : 'Edit',
            name : 'edit'
        }],
    });
});
```

> As well as making use of the Bootstrap styles, the Editor Bootstrap
>   integration also provides a display controller which uses the
>   Bootstrap modal control to fully integrate with Bootstrap.

So, I included [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) library too.

Comment: I include the script for buttons, select, and responsive but for alteditor script I can't include it in my code because my project use HTTPS certificate and is not possible to me to include a link who use HTTPS.

Comment: Save it as a file and include it from your project files. It should work.

Comment: I saved in a file and it works but when I change the data with the edit button I have the notification that it was saved but the data doesn't change. Do you have an idea what the problem is ?

Comment: If your data is coming from server, you better use [Server-side Processing](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/serverSide.html) to process the data requests sent by the client on the server-side.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) script using PHP and [github repo](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/tree/master/examples/server_side) for server-side processing.

Answer (score 0):

There you go;

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytwe0sd5/1/), you must import all the libraries on resources menu and be careful about jQuery version. That was the problem on your fiddle.

```
var data_use = [
    ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422"],
    ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562"],
    ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224"],
    ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407"],
 ];

var column_name = [{
    title: "table_1"
    }, {
    title: "table2"
    }, {
    title: "table3"
    }, {
    title: "table4"
}];

$('#datatable').DataTable({
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    data : data_use,
  columns : column_name,
  dom : 'Bfrtip',
    select : 'single',
    responsive : true,
    altEditor : true,
    destroy : true,
    searching: false,
    buttons: [
          {
            extend: 'selected', 
            text: 'Edit',
            name: 'edit'
         }]
});
```